# MySQL stored procedure: IF in WHERE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select some data in the following manner:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE a = a1
AND (b = b1 OR b = b2 OR b = b3);
```

What I want it to do is if b is not equal to b1, check if b=b2. However, if b=b1, do not check other conditions. 
The result of this select statement must be only one entry. However, in the statement I have no, it checks all of the three conditions and sometimes returns multiple rows. Again, I would like it to stop checking if the condition is true.

Any ideas on how could this be implemented? I tried case but it did not work out...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT
Here is an actual query i am trying to run.

```
INSERT INTO shipment_flights 
    (airlinename, flt_no, flt_date, destination, phone, depttime, arrivaltime, pcs, weight)
SELECT st.airlinename, flightno, flightdate, destination,     
(SELECT phone 
FROM carrierlocations 
WHERE carriers_carrierid = (select carrierid from carriers where airlinename = st.airlinename) 
AND (city = destination OR (city != destination AND
    city = (SELECT city FROM airports WHERE iataid = 
            (SELECT airports_iataid FROM ratelegs 
                WHERE shipments_shipid = c.shipments_shipid))
                ))) phone, 
depttime, arrivaltime, sum(linepcs), sum(lineweight)
FROM segment_times st
    JOIN contents2flights c2f 
        ON st.flightid = c2f.segments_flights_flightid 
        AND st.segmentid = c2f.segments_segmentid 
    JOIN contents c 
        ON c.lineno = c2f.contents_lineno 
        AND c.shipments_shipid = c2f.contents_shipments_shipid

WHERE c.shipments_shipid = var_shipid
GROUP BY flightid
ORDER BY flightdate, depttime;
```

Here is a sample output:

```
airlinename         flt_no  flt_date        destination    phone         pcs   weight
Everts Air Alaska   CH1     2008-02-20      Hughes         9074502351    24    2121
```

The query inserts bunch of flight data into temporary table. What I am having trouble with is getting a phone number for a location. This part is as follows:

```
(SELECT phone 
FROM carrierlocations 
WHERE carriers_carrierid = (select carrierid from carriers where airlinename = st.airlinename) 
AND (city = destination OR (city != destination AND
    city = (SELECT city FROM airports WHERE iataid = 
            (SELECT airports_iataid FROM ratelegs 
                WHERE shipments_shipid = c.shipments_shipid))))) phone
```

In the query advised by Amit Bhargava, I get the right result only if there is one row in the temporary table. If there are  more, it throws an error in the selecting phone part.

"Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Can you please post some sample data/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE a = a1
AND (b = b1 OR (b != b1 AND (b = b2 OR (b != b2 AND b = b3))))
```

Comment: Actually, if `b = b1` is false then `b != b1` is true, and there is no need to check for it. Similar thing happens with `b = b2`. So, if you remove the unnecessary conditions you end up with exactly the same query than the OP asked for :) The result will be the same but this solution is less efficient :P

Comment: shorter: `a = a1 AND (b = b1 OR (b != b1 AND (b = b2 OR (b != b2 AND b = b3))))`

Comment: Now I only have two conditions, (b = b1 OR (b != b1 AND (b = b2))). This returns more than one row if both are true for some reason...

Comment: Instead of `!=` I used `NOT IN`. In my case, if the first condition is true, it checks the second condition with `!=`, returns true and condition after `AND` is true. Therefore it returned 2 rows and threw an error.

Comment: @Nikita In (b = b1 OR (b != b1 AND (b = b2))), under what conditions can both be true? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Amit Bhargava In one table I have an origin city and destination with one carrier (this is one row). Another table has a carrier and cities assigned to the carrier. In this case I check if a destination city is in the cities for the carrier. If not, I check if origin is in that table. However, if both origin and destination are in the second table, both conditions are true. Anyway, instead, I used `NOT IN` and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

By using IF() + IF() + IF(), and testing the sum = 1 prevents a lot of extra and not of the other criteria.  If 2 or all 3 are the same, the summation will be greater than 1.  If none of them match, the result is 0.  This should get exactly what you want.

```
SELECT column
  FROM table
  WHERE a = a1
    AND  if( b = b1, 1, 0 )
       + if( b = b2, 1, 0 )
       + if( b = b3, 1, 0 ) = 1
```

Or... as assisted by ypercube, and I keep forgetting logical tests return either 1 or 0 for true / false respectively, such as...

```
SELECT column
  FROM table
  WHERE a = a1
    AND  (b = b1) + (b = b2) + (b = b3) = 1
```

Comment: @zanlok: You could even write it as: `WHERE a = a1 AND (b=b1)+(b=b2)+(b=b3) = 1`

Comment: @ypercube, thanks for alternate... I keep forgetting that logical returns 1 vs 0.  For such a history of having boolean true/false, forget 1/0 is also viable.

Comment: So, if summation is greater than 1, how would it determine that I need to use the first statement?

Comment: @Nikita, you don't, your entire point is that ONE of the conditions is true and no more, no less.  If 0+0+0, you don't want, 1+1+0 no, 1+0+1 no, 0+1+1 no.  1+0+0 yes, 0+1+0 yes, 0+0+1 yes.